# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, geospatial

I am doing a project which having some functions on Geographical distance calculation. So I use geographical datatypes in entity framework by adding nuget package `SqlServerSpatial110.dll` for that function.

I think my code is correct. Everything is working on local server. But when I uploaded it to server it shows the error below:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

please tell me the steps to upload `SqlServerSpatial110.dll` to server.

Comment: Is you DLL's  CopytoOutputDirectory set to CopyAlways?

Comment: `Copy Local = true` would probably correct that for the 3rd party .dll.. another alternative would be to add a `Lib` Folder to the project and place all the .dll's there that you know would be necessary for all builds and deployment..

Comment: Yes. I set properties as Copy Local = true. But the problem is in serverside.
Is there anything I need to add the reference in the project. Somebody suggests to create Global.asax.cs. I tried that but still the error happens.

Answer (score 9):

Add the reference of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in Web.config of application resolved the issue.

```
<runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding></runtime>
```

Comment: Thank you this works for me in an old winforms application with sqlce4

Answer (score 1):

Please check to make sure the DLLs are installed on the server:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
C:\Windows\System32\SqlServerSpatial110.dll
```

Please check your AppPool. If you are re-using an old AppPool, make sure your AppPool `Advanced Settings` --> `Enable 32-Bit Applications` is `False`.

This fixed my similar problem on a `Windows 2012 Server`.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing worked, try to make
**Platform Target** to be **Any CPU**
Uncheck **Prefer 32-Bit**
Check **Allow Unsafe Code**

The above solution wored for me.